# How to execute the all the tests from the arraylist in .NET Core

Tags: .net-core

We are getting the tests to execute from our testcase management tool and have stored their id in the list .

Example:

```cs
List<string> caseid = new List<string>() [ "tc1", "tc2", "tc3" ]
```

Now I want to execute all the test cases at once/simultaneously to take advantage of my parallel execution system where I an utilise up to 24 browser instance.

Currently I am iterating  over this list and executing as

```
dotnet test --filter TestCategory=caseid[i]
```

Here testcase id is also used as `@tag`.

If there is a way to execute all the tests in the list at once

Comment: `List<string>` is **NOT** an ArrayList.

Comment: Have you read the docs [Run selected unit tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/selective-unit-tests) and [Filter option details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test#filter-option-details)? Lots of good info there...

Comment: yes , but have not found anything which is useful for me in this regards.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn  It could be anything like list or arraylist or simply  a jsonarray. I am looking if I can run all the tests simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following syntax:

```
dotnet test --filter "TestCategory=tc1|TestCategory=tc2|TestCategory=tc3"
```

If you have large number of tests, you can just generate *.sh* file for MacOS or *.cmd* file for windows to run desired batch of tests:

```
var filter = String.Join("|", caseid.Select(id => $"TestCategory={id}"));
File.WriteAllText("./runbatch.sh", $"dotnet test --filter \"{filter}\"");
```

and then run tests in terminal:

```
sh runbatch.sh
```

Comment: In example I have mentioned 3 case but actually the list have more than 100 test cases with scope to grow So adding filter like this is going to be tedious task .

Comment: Why can't you generate script file to run desired tests?

Comment: Thanks all . I already have this solution in place in jenkins pipeline with the help of script. what I was looking for if whichout going for hassle of create the desired string with filtervalues if I can run from the list itself somehow . like for dll if we give the category name as filter then out of all the tests,  command  runs  for the test that filter only. I hope I  am making sense